# array copy keeps changing without edition

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a simple list builder, i can create and edit the list, basicly i have a modal where i build the list after that i can edit it, my issue is if i edit and change the number of items inside the list without pressing the edit, the changes to the list apply. all the rest that i change and don't press edit, works well.

Here is a example:

**my modal edition:**

```
 data () {
    return {
      newItem: '',
      listItem: 0,
      showNewItem: false,
      bulletList: {
        currentSymbol: '•',
        key: 'List',
        items: [

        ],
        ordered: false,
        numbering: 38
      },
      listOptions: [
        { 'symbol': '•', 'number': 37 },
        { 'symbol': '1', 'number': 1 }
      ]
    }
  },
```

in my edition the only thing that can change is the bulletList object, so when i press the edition section it loads the object like this:

```
  mounted () {
    console.log('MOUNTED', this.bulletList.items)
    var sectionKey = this.$store.getters.getCurrentEditionKey
    this.bulletList =_.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey])
  }
```

when i add a item to edit my bulletList and close the configuration modal it added(it shouldn't) the only thing i do when i add a new item is to push it to the local object inside my component, and not the one that i copied from vuex store, strange issue any help? it has something to do with the array behaviour?

```
removeItem () {
  this.bulletList.items.splice(this.listItem, 1)
  this.listItem = 0
},

addNewItem () {
  this.bulletList.items.push(this.newItem)
  this.newItem = ''
},
```

Comment: can you please try to clone the array like `this.bulletList = Object.assign([], yourarray)`.?

Comment: well solved it, the problem was that the i copied the object, but the array inside the object had the reference either